# Failed to collect dependencies error at org.springframework.boot during Maven Build

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data-jpa

Source of project:- [Microservices with Spring, Angular and Kafka](https://dzone.com/articles/developing-async-microservices-architecture-using)

System info: Windows 10 machine with Eclipse IDE.

I am trying to build backend-service folder. I am getting error for Maven given as shown below.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-19T18:22:40+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/489M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project backend-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project poc.microsvc-angular:backend-service:jar:0.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE -> org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:pom:4.3.11.Final from/to public (https://globalrepository.mclocal.int/artifactory/public): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>poc.microsvc-angular</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.plugin.version>0.3.258</docker.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>poc.microsvc-angular</groupId>
            <artifactId>microservice-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>microsvc-angular/${project.name}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <skipDockerBuild>false</skipDockerBuild>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What is the problem?

Is it server problem or dependency hierarchy problem?

Or is it a corrupt jar ?(I tried deleting, still does not work)

Comment: from your log you can see that `https://globalrepository.mclocal.int/artifactory/public` is unreachable